# Skydrive can't connect to Microsoft Servers

Tags: onedrive

I've installed SkyDrive on my computer, however I can't seem to get it to connect. It keeps saying there's a problem with the SkyDrive servers. I've reinstalled it several times, and I know I have the right login.

Comment: How have you confirmed correct logon?

Comment: It works on live.com. Also, a box pops up saying there was a problem with the server, so it might not have even gotten that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be a DNS issue. Try setting the DNS server on your computer to `8.8.8.8`. That's Google's servers, and that fixed the problem for me. Go to your connection status > Properties. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 and click Properties. Click "Use the following DNS server" and type in `8.8.8.8`. Close all the windows, clicking Ok or Close, then try again.